# Chaquopy upgrade pip

Tags: chaquopy

While running the latest chaquopy I am running into the error:

```
Collecting tensorflow==1.13.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.13.1 (from versions: 1.10.1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.13.1
```

I am wondering if the internal chaquopy pip is too old and needs to be upgraded. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the version of pip, it's the version of TensorFlow. Try changing your project to use version 1.10.1 instead, as the message suggests.

Comment: The given version is required for the model I have built

Comment: @JacobB: OK, please report an issue on the [Chaquopy GitHub page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues), explaining exactly why this version is required.